# PhpStorm Settings Repository Commit on repo without HEAD not supported

Tags: github, repository, phpstorm, settings

I'm trying to setup a Settings Repository on GitHub.

After creating a new GitHub account and a new repository if I enter the repository upstream URL in the Settings Repository dialog of PhpStorm I receive this error message:

> Failed to Sync Settings: Commit on repo without HEAD currently not supported

How I can solve this?

Comment: Looks like some unaddressed issue: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-152002. You might want to attach your idea.log file (Help > Show log) there and comment that you're having the same issue

Comment: Any chance you found a solution to this? Our development is at a standstill because of this issue

Comment: No solution yet , sorry :(

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This seems to be a bug in the *Settings repository plugin* of different JetBrains IDEs. A functioning workaround is to delete the local Git repository in the IDE's config directory:

```
${HOME}/.<IDE>/config/settingsRepository/repository
```

Please refer to this site for the exact directory name of your IDE on your operating system:

https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544519-Directories-used-by-the-IDE-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs

The workaround was posted in the JetBrains bug report (for IntelliJ IDEA):

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-152002#comment=27-2918113

Answer (score 0):

Go into "%appdata%\JetBrains\PhpStorm2020.2\settingsRepository" (change the path to match your version of PHPStorm and then rename the folder named "repository" to something else, then you can setup the project correctly. :)