# PhpStorm Settings Repository Commit on repo without HEAD not supported - no <IDE> folder

Tags: git, repository, bitbucket, phpstorm, settings

I'm having the same issue as noted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48618774/phpstorm-settings-repository-commit-on-repo-without-head-not-supported), but the `${HOME}/.<IDE>/` directory doesn't exist because I installed PhpStorm on my mac via the JetBrains Toolbox (rendering the existing answer to the OP's question invalid).

Every time PhpStorm updates to a new release, all my settings disappear, so I first tried the sync to my JetBrains account but that never worked. I then tried creating the Settings repository and PhpStorm was committing settings changes to the repository but lo and behold, as soon as PhpStorm updated itself all my settings are gone and now I too am getting this `Failed to Sync Settings: Commit on repo without HEAD currently not supported` error when I try to pull my settings from the remote repository.

Not sure if it is relevant or not, but I chose Bitbucket as the host for my (private) settings repository.

Comment: *"...but the `${HOME}/.<IDE>/` directory doesn't exist..."* On Mac it uses different location than Windows/Linux. See https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544519-Directories-used-by-the-IDE-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs

Comment: I ended up upgrading to the EAP release, and then back to the latest stable release and the problem seems to have gone away...

Answer (score 0):

That problem happens when the settings sync configuration have failed the first time. To fix it go to "%appdata%\JetBrains\PhpStorm2020.2\settingsRepository" (change the path to match your version of PHPStorm) and then rename the folder named "repository" to something else, then you can setup the project correctly. :)